# A little bit of SEO: how to make a very simple website prettier in search engine results?

Tags: optimization, seo, sitemap

[image: screenshot]

Look, under page title there's a very nice link, including categories of the website.

I really do want that thing on my website. The problem is the syntax of my website:

```
Main page: index.php
Category: index.php?p=part&id=[ID]
Subcategory: index.php?p=cat&id=[ID]
Article: index.php?p=post&id=[ID]
```

What should I do? Changing syntax is no good for me, but I'm pretty sure I can do some magic with htaccess RewriteEngine, but it's not going to look much better.

Huge thanks in advance :)

---

Ooops, almost forgot. Can I have some kind of guide to a proper sitemap? I already searched for it myself, but every guide offers it's own way to make it, and I'm totally confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called microdata. You can find the officially supported microdata at [schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html). Keep in mind that using microdata does not guarantee your search results will be affected.

Answer (score 2):

These breadcrumb links in the SERPS are not only from microdata, but are from the breadcrumb navigation links on the sites pages. (which can indeed be marked up with microdata, but do not have to be) Google will tend to use them if urls are very long in my experience.

More info here:

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/new-site-hierarchies-display-in-search.html

and here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=-LH5eyufqH0#!

and here

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185417